# input 1D array into 2D array in increasing order (C)

Tags: c, arrays, matrix

I need to build a program, that requesting from user to insert a sentence
like "Hello World" or whatever

and than take this sentence and input it inside 1D array

and from there to input it in 2D array that will present his sentence in this order:

```
Hello!! :)
)Hello!! :
:)Hello!! 
 :)Hello!!
! :)Hello!
!! :)Hello
o!! :)Hell
lo!! :)Hel
llo!! :)He
ello!! :)H
```

I did most of the job done, but i can't make it exactly like this
i mean
its present me the sentence decreasing and not increasing

my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define P 10
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    char array1[P][P];
    char array2[P];
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i<P; i++) //fill the array with the chars.
    {
        scanf("%c", &array2[i]);
    }

    for (i=0 ; i<P ; i++)
    {
        for (j=0 ; j<P ; j++)
        {
            array1[i][j] = array2[j+i];
        }
    }

    for (i=0 ; i<P ; i++)
    {
        for (j=0 ; j<P ; j++)
        {
            printf("%c", array1[i][j]);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }

}
```

where is my mistake? and how i can fix it?
Thanks.

Comment: Are you required to use a 2d array? You can achieve the same with O(P) space complexity by using a single array of length 2P.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code during entering in `array1` for first run of your outer loop is correct but for second time it is inserting value at `array1[1][0]=array2[1];` means second element of the `array2` so use this

```
array1[i][j] = array2[(j+P-i)%P];
```

Answer (score 0):

`array1[i][j] = array2[j+i];` should be `array1[i][j] = array2[(j+P-i)%P];`